# Cordova Local Build Fails because of app size?

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant

I have an app that is using 50M in total just to hold all UI and the actual build.
Then I have a folder "platforms/android/res/raw" where I add my video files.
I have 6 video files that sums up to 110M, so in total we have 160M + cordova.

When I have my raw folder with only 1 video in it, I can compile it and get the apk out.
When I keep all 6 videos in there my ant debug fails straight away. I don't think it's a code issue, but maybe it's a configuration (for compilation capacity), or is it me? It's probably me, that's got to be said.

So when I go

```
ant debug -f "/Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/XXX/platforms/android/build.xml"
```

I get this output

```
    Eds-Mac-mini:XXX ed$ ant debug -f "/Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/build.xml"
    Buildfile: /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/build.xml

    -set-mode-check:

    -set-debug-files:

    -check-env:
     [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
     [checkenv] Installed at /Users/ed/Eclipse/sdk

    -setup:
         [echo] Project Name: XXX
      [gettype] Project Type: Application

    -set-debug-mode:

    -debug-obfuscation-check:

    -pre-build:

    -build-setup:
    [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.1
         [echo] Resolving Build Target for XXX...
    [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
    [gettarget] API level:        19
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Resolving Dependencies for XXX...
    [dependency] Library dependencies:
    [dependency]
    [dependency] ------------------
    [dependency] Ordered libraries:
    [dependency]
    [dependency] ------------------
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

    nodeps:

    -set-mode-check:

    -set-debug-files:

    -check-env:
     [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
     [checkenv] Installed at /Users/ed/Eclipse/sdk

    -setup:
         [echo] Project Name: CordovaLib
      [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

    -set-debug-mode:

    -debug-obfuscation-check:

    -pre-build:

    -build-setup:
    [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.1
         [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaLib...
    [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
    [gettarget] API level:        19
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaLib...
    [dependency] Library dependencies:
    [dependency] No Libraries
    [dependency]
    [dependency] ------------------

    -code-gen:
    [mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
         [echo] Handling aidl files...
         [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling Resources...
         [aapt] No changed resources. R.java and Manifest.java untouched.
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
    [buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

    -pre-compile:

    -compile:
         [echo] Creating library output jar file...

    -post-compile:

    -obfuscate:

    -dex:
         [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

    -crunch:
       [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
       [crunch] To destination dir: /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/CordovaLib/bin/res
       [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

    -package-resources:
         [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

    -package:
         [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

    -post-package:

    -do-debug:
         [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop
    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop
    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop
    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop

    -post-build:

    debug:

    -code-gen:
    [mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
         [echo] Handling aidl files...
         [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling Resources...
         [aapt] Found new input file
         [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
    [buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

    -pre-compile:

    -compile:
        [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/bin/classes
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:17: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 1=0x7f040000;
        [javac]                                ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:17: illegal start of type
        [javac]         public static final int 1=0x7f040000;
        [javac]                                  ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:17: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 1=0x7f040000;
        [javac]                                   ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:18: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 2=0x7f040001;
        [javac]                                ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:18: illegal start of type
        [javac]         public static final int 2=0x7f040001;
        [javac]                                  ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:18: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 2=0x7f040001;
        [javac]                                   ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:19: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 3=0x7f040002;
        [javac]                                ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:19: illegal start of type
        [javac]         public static final int 3=0x7f040002;
        [javac]                                  ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:19: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 3=0x7f040002;
        [javac]                                   ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:20: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 4=0x7f040003;
        [javac]                                ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:20: illegal start of type
        [javac]         public static final int 4=0x7f040003;
        [javac]                                  ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:20: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 4=0x7f040003;
        [javac]                                   ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:21: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 5=0x7f040004;
        [javac]                                ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:21: illegal start of type
        [javac]         public static final int 5=0x7f040004;
        [javac]                                  ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:21: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 5=0x7f040004;
        [javac]                                   ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:22: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 6=0x7f040005;
        [javac]                                ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:22: illegal start of type
        [javac]         public static final int 6=0x7f040005;
        [javac]                                  ^
        [javac] /Users/ed/Desktop/Projects/Local/kiosk_cordova/XXX/platforms/android/gen/com/xxx/kiosk/R.java:22: <identifier> expected
        [javac]         public static final int 6=0x7f040005;
        [javac]                                   ^
        [javac] 18 errors

    BUILD FAILED
    /Users/ed/Eclipse/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    /Users/ed/Eclipse/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    Total time: 4 seconds
```

So from what I gather it's struggling with R.java file, so here's my R.java file...
        package com.xxx.kiosk;

```
    public final class R {
        public static final class attr {
        }
        public static final class drawable {
            public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
        }
        public static final class raw {
            public static final int 1=0x7f040000;
            public static final int 2=0x7f040001;
            public static final int 3=0x7f040002;
            public static final int 4=0x7f040003;
            public static final int 5=0x7f040004;
            public static final int 6=0x7f040005;
        }
        public static final class string {
            public static final int app_name=0x7f050000;
        }
        public static final class style {
            public static final int XXX=0x7f060000;
        }
        public static final class xml {
            public static final int config=0x7f030000;
        }
    }
```

*Project name is not XXX but is replaced so if anyone things XXX is the reason, it's not.*

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally figured out what is the issue.
Please be careful if anyone gets this as well.

Apparently Cordova creates this class and creates variables based on file names.
My video files were called 1.mp4;2.mp4;3.mp4 etc. As you know class methods / variables cannot start with 0-9, adding a-z in front of 0-9 solves the issue.